# How to create a Class that supports mutation via "obj.MyDate.AddDays"?

Tags: c#, class, datetime, properties, struct

I would like to create a property backed by a `DateTime` struct, however, because structs are value types, `MyClass.MyDate.AddDays(1)` doesn't work as expected for the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

The desired behavior would be to have the DateTime property increase by one day, but in my example, the property keeps it's initial value. I can get the same result with the code `MyClass.MyDate = MyClass.DateTime.AddDays(1)`, but this is counterintuitive.  I understand why this doesn't work, but I'm not sure of the best way to work around it.

What is the accepted way to create the MyDate property so that the exposed DateTime methods like AddDays() update the instance variable?

Comment: That behavior has nothing to do with the fact that it's a struct/value type.  It is because .AddDays returns a new DateTime and has no effect on the instance you call it on.

Comment: While many of you have given the same advice, I'm accepting @kendfrey's answer b/c it gives a code example that answers my question. Turns out the source of my confusion was that I was confusing what my getter returns and what AddDays() returns. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyClass.MyDate = MyClass.DateTime.AddDays(1)`

This is the standard behavior of a struct. All standards-compliant structs are immutable, except those with a VERY good reason.

If you really have a problem with the above syntax, I recommend something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }

    public void AddDays(double days)
    {
        this.MyDate = this.MyDate.AddDays(days);
    }
}
```

Comment: (True, but it could technically not be a struct and *still* be immutable. In any case, yes, a wrapper "action" does the trick.)

Comment: "All structs are immutable" - I believe this is wrong. Could you please support this with a reference?

Comment: @zespri: I changed the wording of the post.

Comment: @kendfrey: thanks, would be nice to know *what* standards do you have in mind. Could you let me know please?

Comment: @pst: concept of final is common to java world it is not standard terminology in .NET world. You are confusing design time and run-time. Immutable means can't be changed in run-time. Final means can't be used for deriving other types from. Those two are different things.

Comment: @pst: I'd like to explore this further, but don't want to derail the discussion. I'm still not sure what you mean by "cannot be changed after the struct is created" if it's not about subclassing.

Comment: @zespri Apparently my brain is not functioning today :( Previously wildly inaccurate comments removed.

Comment: @zespri: I was thinking mostly of the unspoken standard which every respectable programmer ahderes to. But I imagine there is mention of the topic somewhere in the major 'official' C# standards.

Comment: I think this is relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx Edit: and actually the whole series: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/immutability/

Answer (score 1):

`AddDays` and the other methods will never update the contents of the field or property, because they do not update the value itself. Instead they *return* a new value with the adjustments.

You can easily test this with this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
Debug.WriteLine(dt);
dt.AddDays(1);
Debug.WriteLine(dt);
```

You will get the same date printed twice. The fact that you're doing this through a property has no relation to the problem here.

If you need to have method calls, I would consider adding them directly to your class instead.

For instance, you would call this:

```
mc.AddDays(1);
```

instead of doing this:

```
mc.MyDate = mc.MyDate.AddDays(1);
```

However, I would seriously consider not doing it at all. It adds a lot of cruft to your own class here.

Instead, I might consider the time saved by *not* doing this as money saved, and putting those into buying [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), as it has inspections that would tell you that `dt.AddDays(1);` has no effect (at least for the cases it knows about, like DateTime.)

Answer (score 0):

You have shown the accepted way to do this - since `DateTime` is immutable assign the result of `AddDays()` to the property again. The fact that `DateTime` is immutable actually saves your bacon here, since if it wasn't you would be tempted to **not** assign back to the property again, which of course would not have the expected outcome since you are mutating a copy that goes nowhere.

The only other way to do this in an "intuitive" way would be to use a decorator class to wrap `DateTime` which then can safely modify it any way you want it to. I would not recommend doing this though, since in my opinion this adds more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that you problem has nothing to do with `DateTime` being struct. 'String`is not struct, but it's immutable the same way`DateTime` is so MyString.Substring(1,2) won't give you what you expect either.

Also my opinion is that for an experienced developer there is nothing counter-intuitive about this behaviour. Knowing that DateTime is immutable, it would never cross my mind that `MyClass.MyDate.AddDays(1)` is supposed to change the property value. Why would it?

In the end I do not think that you have a problem that needs to be solved, you simply need to get more comfortable with the way c# and .net works

Comment: Actually, it does have to with DateTime being a struct. Just because one class is immutable, does not mean that structs are not immutable.

Comment: @kendfrey: structs are not immutable. Could you please provide a reference that supports your statement. You can test the fact that they are not immutable by creating a struct with a settable property, and then changing the property value. The value will indeed change, that proves that the struct is not inherently immutable.

Comment: OK, structs per se are not immutable. Standards-compliant structs are.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass() { MyDate = DateTime.Now };
myClass.MyDate += new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
```